# Need title for a section in my UX case study

Tags: onboarding, portfolio, case-studies, competitive-analysis

There is this case study that I am writing which is about onboarding users on to the product. The product is platform as a service(PaaS). For designing the onbaording alone I looked into a lot of SaaS products and their onboarding flows to seek inspiration, figure market trends and most importantly the missing pieces in our existing onboarding flow.  What should I call this study? Competitive analysis? But they aren't competitors? Benchmarking? But I am not measuring anything

Comment: I would call this desk research or pattern research. My advice to you as a hiring manager - this is fine as *part* of a discovery process, but you'll want to show that you do more than just look at other products and copy them in your case study.

Comment: This was a feature, typically we do not have access to customers, we do have some data as evidence to support our hypothesis, but that's about it...we tested the existing onboarding with a few users internally...should I then add all of this too?

Comment: Yes, I'd recommend adding that, as well as the outcomes that the redesign achieved based on the research.

Answer (score 1):

You could call it background research, which is what I feel like the content is covering.

I guess you'll also want to reference other research activities conducted within the company, and see if there are some common terms used to make it easier for other people to find your work.

Answer (score 1):

It is acually Desk Research but to be more specific, Maybe you can call it "Competitive Audit". I would suggest do a SWOT analysis post that.